# Can I manipulate the indexing process?

Tags: index, debugging

Is it possible to start an indexing process and then deliberately pause it maintaining the `processing` status for testing purposes?

The example in specific that I am trying to debug is a rare occurrence during which `Product Prices` index becomes stuck during processing and stops product saves from occurring due to SQL deadlocks & serialization failures.

I'd like to simulate this behaviour so that I can test potential solutions for the problem (i.e verifying `var/locks` directory & attempt an event-observer approach to stop the serialization failure issues)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling all the indexes, cron entry and run via shell `php -f shell/indexer.php` you could [CMD/CTRL+C SIGINT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29654/is-ctrlc-incorrect-to-use-to-return-to-command-line) the indexer you are needing to test during operation.  This should cause Webserver/PHP not to continue and as long as no cron is setup no further operation should persist. Another option would be to open a second terminal and `kill -9 <pid>` the process more forceful if SIGINT isn't cutting it.

However, you probably have a common issue others are having as the source of the issue:

- [Price re-index causes DB deadlocks during checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260/price-re-index-causes-db-deadlocks-during-checkout)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412838/deadlock-issue-when-transaction-tries-to-accuire-a-lock-its-already-holding

One possibility as well is to implement some type of FPC if you are not to take some of the requests off of MySQL to prevent any deadlocks during reindexing.