# Having issue in reindex while i m reindexing product price

Tags: magento-1.9.3.8

There was a problem with reindexing process. SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1,

> Query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price` (`entity_id`,
>   `customer_group_id`, `website_id`, `tax_class_id`, `price`,
>   `final_price`, `min_price`, `max_price`, `tier_price`, `group_price`,
>   `vendor_id`) SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`entity_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`customer_group_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`website_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`tax_class_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`final_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`min_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`max_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`tier_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`group_price` FROM
>   `catalog_product_index_price_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id`
>   = VALUES(`entity_id`), `customer_group_id` = VALUES(`customer_group_id`), `website_id` = VALUES(`website_id`),
>   `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`),
>   `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` =
>   VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` =
>   VALUES(`tier_price`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`),
>   `vendor_id` = VALUES(`vendor_id`)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

https://www.tigren.com/fix-deadlock-error-reindexing-magento-2/

and

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

and then reindex all again.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Should be work

Comment: this issue related to magento1 sir can anyone help me get exact solution

Comment: Please try reset index and again reindex. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260/price-re-index-causes-db-deadlocks-during-checkout

Comment: how to reset index in magento as i m new to magento

Comment: Please open SSH and go to your main catalog magento and run command php bin/magento indexer:reset Yesterday I have similar issue in my M2 and solve for me.

Comment: this is for magento2 i m getting this error in magento1